# Filter pandas frame based on example row with "wildcard" values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and a filter I want to apply to the frame in the form of a series. The filtered dataframe should include all rows that match the filter. Where the filter has a "wildcard-value", defined in this case as NaN, everything is considered a match.

Below is my implementation of such a filter:

```
df: pandas.DataFrame
f: pandas.Series

def match(row: pandas.Series, f: pandas.Series):
    return all([isinstance(value, float) and math.isnan(value) or value == row[idx] 
                for idx, value in zip(f.index, f)])

filtered_df = df[[match(row, f) for _, row in df.iterrows()]]
```

It does the job, but it's not as elegant as I would like and might be to slow for large `df`. I have heard that iterating over pandas frames is frowned upon and am therefore looking for a better solution.

How can one write this code in a better way?

Update with runnable code:

```
import math
import pandas

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {'Name': ['Ankit', 'Amit', 'Aishwarya', 'Priyanka'],
            'Age': [21, 19, 19, 19],
            'Stream': ['Math', 'Commerce', 'Arts', 'Biology'],
            'Percentage': [88, 88, 88, 70]}

    df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Stream', 'Percentage'])

    f = pandas.Series([math.nan, 19, math.nan, 88], index=['Name', 'Age', 'Stream', 'Percentage'])


    def match(row: pandas.Series, f: pandas.Series):
        return all([isinstance(value, float) and math.isnan(value) or value == row[idx]
                    for idx, value in zip(f.index, f)])


    filtered_df = df[[match(row, f) for _, row in df.iterrows()]]

    print(filtered_df)
```

Comment: could you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and the desired filtered output to it? Also few more words about what exactly your filter should do would be good.

Comment: There is a typo in your code, you call the function "match" with row and `f`, but `f` is not defined.

Comment: f is defined at row 2 in the code segment.

Comment: as I said, please add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with data we need to run your code or to answer your question. Like this there isn't much we can do.

Comment: There is now runnable code @Rabinzel.

Comment: Took a bit to get my head around the logic. Am I missing something or can there be whatever value in `Name` and `Stream`? It has no impact on the filter (that's what you meant with wildcard I guess), the only rule is that only the rows of the `df` get filtered, which have the same value in `Age` and `Percentage` as in the Series `f`?

Comment: Yes. In this case, since the columns are set to NaN in the filter, they will always be considered a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use an inner join to keep only the relevant rows, like this example:

```
# Remove indexes without condition
f = f.dropna()

# Move the series into a DataFrame (T needed to transpose)
f_frame = f.to_frame().T

# Perform inner join
filtered_df = df.merge(f_frame, how='inner', on=list(f_frame.columns))
```

Comment: This seems very promising, I'll try  it today and get back to you.